# Copying file from Unix to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: unix, sharepoint-2010

I need to copy a file from Unix to Sharepoint 2010 team site... Is there an API that does that?  If not, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 provides a number of SOAP based web services that you can call to upload files, manipulate list items, etc.  See here for more information:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814.aspx

Alternatively, SharePoint 2010 provides UNC path access to document libraries.  For example, you can access a document library located at `http://myserver/mysite/mylibrary` by `\\myserver\mysite\mylibrary`.  How you would do this from a UNIX machine, I don't know, but hopefully that points you in the right direction.